# How declare a object in angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, object, web

I am newbie using Angular and I have an issue with object declaration in angular component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clases',
  templateUrl: './clases.component.html'

})
export class ClasesComponent
{

  alerta:string="alert-danger";

  constructor() {  }

  propiedades:Object = {
    danger: false
  }

}
```

when I try to compile this code I get an error

***Compiled with problems:

```
Error: src/app/components/clases/clases.component.html:9:76 - error TS2339: Property 'danger' does not exist on type 'Object'.

9 <h3 [ngClass]=" {'text-danger':propiedades.danger,'text-info':!propiedades.danger  }">
                                                                             ~~~~~~

  src/app/components/clases/clases.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './clases.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ClasesComponent.
```

It seems that danger propoerty in the class doesnt exist but it is there so give that error

Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to add the type of variable propiedades to become like this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clases',
  templateUrl: './clases.component.html'
})
export class ClasesComponent {
  alerta = 'alert-danger';
 
  propiedades: {danger: boolean} = {
    danger: false
  };

  constructor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript has more than sufficient information to figure out the object type by itself, so you can just do:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clases',
  templateUrl: './clases.component.html'
})
export class ClasesComponent {
  alerta = 'alert-danger';
 
  propiedades = {
    danger: false
  };

  constructor() {}
}
```

If you explicitly type it as `Object`, and evaluate this template line:

```
<h3 [ngClass]=" {'text-danger':propiedades.danger,'text-info':!propiedades.danger }">
```

The Angular/TypeScript compiler will expect a value of type [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), which indeed has no `danger` property.

Comment: Thks! it works! Put off declaration Object

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to declare Objects in TypeScript using the interface.

---

1st - When we know the exact keys then we have to use an interface like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface Propiedades {
    danger: Boolean;    
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clases',
  templateUrl: './clases.component.html'

})
export class ClasesComponent
{

  alerta:string="alert-danger";

  constructor() {  }

  propiedades: Propiedades = {
    danger: false
  }

}
```

2nd - When we don't know exact keys then we have to use an interface like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface Propiedades {
    [key: string]: Boolean;    
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clases',
  templateUrl: './clases.component.html'

})
export class ClasesComponent
{

  alerta:string="alert-danger";

  constructor() {  }

  propiedades: Propiedades = {
    danger: false
  }

}
```